# What statistic method to use in multivariate abundance data with random effects?

Tags: glm, multivariate-testing

I am working with multivariate data with random effects.
My hypothesis is this: `D` has an effect on `A1` and `A2`, where `A1` and `A2` are binary data, and `D` is a continuous variable.
I also have a random effect, `R`, that is a factor variable.

So my model would be something like this: `A1andA2~D, random=1=~1|R`

I tried to use the function `manyglm` in `mvabund` package, but it can not deal with random effects. Or I can use `lme4`, but it can not deal with multivariate data.

I can convert my multivariate data to a 4 level factor variable, but I didn't find any method to use not binary but factor data as a response variable. I also can convert the continuous `D` into factor variable.

Do you have any advice about what to use in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

First, I know this should be a comment and not a complete answer but I can't comment yet and thought you might still appreciate the pointer.

You should be able to analyze your data with the MCMCglmm R package. [(see here for an Intro)](https://github.com/tmalsburg/MCMCglmm-intro), as it can handle mixed models with multivariate response data.